# How do I load a MySQL timestamp field into a specific format from a flat file?

Tags: mysql, date

I have some data in a flat file that includes a timestamp field that looks like `1900-01-01 00:00:00`. I've been trying to load it into a MySQL table but MySQL is taking it and setting it as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` which is causing issues for me. I've tried running some `update` commands on the field, but it stays as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

I know of the `from_unixtime` function, but how would I use that here? This is the command I'm running to load the data:

`load data local infile 'file.txt' into table tgt_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'' (tbl_name, db_name, timestamp_field, other_col);`

The field in question here is `timestamp_field`.

I've managed to use `from_unixtime` like `update tgt_table set timestamp_field=FROM_UNIXTIME('1900-01-01 00:00:00') where tbl_name = 'test';` but timestamp_field ended up looking like: `1969-12-31 18:31:40`

Would appreciate any help on how to format either the column or the SQL to get this inserted correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it might be a column type issue.

From the [MySQL 5.6 documentation on time/date fields](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html):

`The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.`

You used the 1900-01-01 in your example which is outside the allowable date range for timestamp. Instead, try using a DATETIME field which has a larger allowable range.

`The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.`

Comment: Ah thanks. That's such a weird range/constraint for Timestamp.